# Character array in c with function

Tags: c

I have a problem with a character array in my c program.

The program immediately shutdown when I run it. I think the problem is somewhere with passing the character array in the function.

here's my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define DAGEN 7

void inlezen(int[][DAGEN], char[][12]);

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    int temp[1][DAGEN];

    char dagen[7][12];

    strcpy(dagen[0], "MA");
    strcpy(dagen[1], "DI");
    strcpy(dagen[2], "WOE");
    strcpy(dagen[3], "DO");
    strcpy(dagen[4], "VR");
    strcpy(dagen[5], "ZA");
    strcpy(dagen[6], "ZO");



    inlezen(temp, 1, DAGEN, dagen, 7, 12);

}

void inlezen(int t[][DAGEN], char d[][12])
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < DAGEN; i++)
    {
        printf("Geef de temperatuur overdag van %s", d[i]);
        scanf("%d%*c", &t[0][i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < DAGEN; i++)
    {
        printf("Geef de temperatuur 's avonds van %s", d[i]);
        scanf("%d%*c", &t[1][i]);
    }

}
```

I've edited my code, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: char dagen[6][12]; should be char dagen[7][12];

Comment: Still doesn't work...

Comment: Why are you passing `inlezen(temp, 1, DAGEN, dagen, 6, 12);` six parameters when your function only takes two? `void inlezen(int t[][DAGEN], char d[][12])`

Comment: `int temp[2][DAGEN]; char dagen[DAGEN][12];`, `scanf("%d", &t[0][i]);`,`scanf("%d", &t[1][i]);`

Comment: The size you give in an array declaration is not the top index, it's the number of elements in the array. So declaring an array of seven elements (with indexes `0` through `6` (inclusive)) you specify `7` as the size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code

```
 strcpy(dagen[6], "ZO");
```

you're accessing out of bound memory by using 6 as the index value. Your definition of `dagen`

```
 char dagen[6][12];
```

only permits a valid access up to 5 as the first index. 
]
By using 6, it invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

FWIW, C uses `0` based indexing for arrays.

That said, the call

```
 inlezen(temp, 1, DAGEN, dagen, 6, 12);
```

does not match the function signature, at all.

Finally, `scanf()` family expects a pointer to variable type of arguments for supplied format specifiers, so, the

```
  scanf("%d%*c", t[0][i]);
```

statements should be actually

```
  scanf("%d%*c", &t[0][i]);
```

and likewise.

Answer (score 1):

```
void inlezen(int[][DAGEN], char[][12]);
```

See this prototype you declared

and what values you pass to it -`inlezen(temp, 1, DAGEN, dagen, 6, 12);` in `main`.

And this  `strcpy(dagen[6], "ZO");` .Declaration of array was `char dagen[6][12];`  so index can go from `0` to `5`.You access out of bound memory ,thus invokes **UB**.Either remove this line or increase size to `char dagen[7][12];`

These statements -

```
 scanf("%d%*c", t[0][i]);
 .....
 scanf("%d%*c", t[1][i]);
```

should be -

```
scanf("%d",&t[0][i]);
 .....
scanf("%d",&t[1][i]);
```